# What's the difference between 'bump my head' and 'hit my head'?

Tags: difference

With 'hit my head', I tend to think I hit my head using some object like a stick while I don't move my head. On the other hand, I understand with 'bump my head' as I move my head toward the wall and hit the wall with my head.

But I also feel they are actually the same expressions. Are they different or the same?

Comment: If your head accidentally makes contact with a hard surface, you can say either that you hit it or bumped it (but _bump_ is a more informal expression that you wouldn't use if it looked like being a serious injury). "I hit my head" _could_ mean that you struck your own head with a weapon, but that would more likely be expressed as "I hit myself on the head."

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. Your comment nails it, especially, the sentence I hit myself on the head. How about posting your comment as an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your head accidentally makes contact with a hard surface, you can say either that you hit it or bumped it (but *bump* is a more informal expression that you wouldn't use if it looked like being a serious injury).

"I hit my head" *could* mean that you struck your own head with a weapon, but that would more likely be expressed as "I hit myself on the head."